# Kronig-Penney Model Boundary Value Assertion

Tags: condensed-matter, schroedinger-equation

I've been doing some work pertaining to Condensed Matter Physics and have been trying to fully understand the derivativion of solutions to the Kronig-Penney Model. I've looked at tutorials from several different sites, however the example presented [here](https://lampx.tugraz.at/%7Ehadley/ss1/KronigPenney/KronigPenney.php) asserts about halfway down the page that the wave functions for the two regions, $\psi_1(x)$ and $\psi_2(x)$ are chosen to have the properties
\begin{gather}
\psi_1(0) = 1\\
\frac{d\psi_1}{dx}(0) = 0\\
\psi_2(0) = 0\\
\frac{d\psi_2}{dx}(0) = 1
\end{gather}
Could someone explain to me why this assertion is allowed to be made? Unfortunately, my quantum mechanics skills are bit rusty. I'm hoping this will ultimately aid in the calculation for the coefficients $A,B,C,D$ from the two general equations. Any help regarding this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a misunderstanding. $\psi_1$ and $\psi_2$ are not wavefunctions in different regions. **In each region**, one is considering two wavefunctions. The properties of the [Wronskian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wronskian) ensure that if the conditions
\begin{gather}
\psi_1 = 1\\
\frac{d\psi_1}{dx} = 0\\
\psi_2 = 0\\
\frac{d\psi_2}{dx} = 1 \tag{1}
\end{gather}
hold at one point, the Wronskian is non-zero over the whole interval. A non-zero Wronsiak is equivalent to the linear independence of the two functions. Therefore, conditions (1) are nothing but a convenient way to request that $\psi_1$ and $\psi_2$ are linearly independent solutions in each interval.
Once obtained, the most general solution of the differential equation can be obtained as a linear combination of them.

Comment: Would the idea be that I can assert any values in the Wronskian so long as the columns are linearly independent? For instance, I could just as well say $\psi_1(0) = 1$, $\psi_1'(0) = 1$, $\psi_2(0) = 1$, $\psi_2'(0) = -1$. Am I correct there? I understand that this would be a messier choice and thus not preferred but still allowed.

Comment: @DavidG. Yes, it's that way.